# Create a new file based on matching between two files

Tags: macos, unix, sed, grep

I am having two files

First file is in this format. Each line starts with unique id (in this case P22465)

```
P22465    DB   DB; EC.31.1.1; the annexin (annexin) group.
```

Second file is in this format.Each line starts with (some number)@ENTREZGENE

```
309@ENTREZGENE|ANXA6_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|P08133@SWISSPROT|ANXA6:ANXA6|67 kDa calelectrin

30@ENTREZGENE|THIK_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|P22465@SWISSPROT|ACAA1:ACAA1|EC 2.3.1.16
```

Output should be

```
30@ENTREZGENE|THIK_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|P22465@SWISSPROT|ACAA1:ACAA1|EC 2.3.1.16
```

It should match the line containing unique id (P22465) in the second file and copy the whole line to the new file

Comment: Cool. Nice. And what? :)

Comment: Great problem statement.  What's the question?

Comment: copy the whole line of which file? pls add file2 and output

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.Please find the  edited question

Comment: So you want to divide the second file into many files, according to the third field. How is the first file involved?

Comment: First file has P22465 based on which second line is selected from second  file. In brief I want to create a new file with extracted  lines from second file based on string match which is present in first file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bash`:

```
fgrep -f <(awk '{print $1}' file1) file2
```

This uses process substitution (`<(...)`).  You could probably also do it with:

```
awk '{print $1}' file1 | fgrep -f - file2
```

This tells `fgrep` to 'read the strings to be matched from standard input' (`-f -`).  I've not verified that this works, but I'd expect it to do so.

You can use `grep -F` in lieu of `fgrep` (but Mac OS X has `fgrep`).